# background image is not displaying in browser in angular

Tags: angular

I have to cover an image entire background for that I have written code in SCSS in angular project but it not going to display in browser. If anyone know the solution for this please answer for this question.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.container {
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
height: 100%;
background-image: url('../../assets/images/Rectangle\ 12.png') no-repeat;
// background-position: center;
// background-repeat: no-repeat;
// background-size: cover;
// background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: `background-image: url('../../assets/images/Rectangle\ 12.png')` change to `background-image: url('../../assets/images/Rectangle/12.png')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @debuggger. I tried it but no result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To set a percentage value for height, the parent's height must be determined then only height will work. otherwise you can specify the height and width manually like following and also remove no-repeat from background-image:

```
 .container {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../../assets/images/Rectangle\ 12.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Borad Akash. I tried it but no result

Comment: Can you provide me stackblitz link?

Answer (score 0):

The `\`  in your file name: `Rectangle\ 12.png` tells me you copied a filename with a space.

I would avoid spaces in files when dealing with urls. Just cause the correct way of writing spaces is `%20` so file name would be `Rectangle%2012.png`. It make it get confusing to read. Rename the file with a `_` or `-` to make it more readable.

Other than that don't bother with relative paths in you css url functions in angular. If you rename the file space with `_` the path would be `url('/assets/images/Rectangle_12.png')` else if you leave as is it would be with `%20` as the space so meaning: `url('/assets/images/Rectangle%2012.png')`